# Hebrew in Texpad

Tags: texpad

I am trying to write a Hebrew article using Texpad editor in macOS, However, I encounter  the following problems:

The text I type is written 'left to right' how do I change to 'right to left'?

How do I choose the font for my pdf doc? is there a possibility to check what fonts are available?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setmainfont{David}
\title{The title}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\fontspec{David}

Test Test Test
\newline
ניסון ניסון ניסון 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! My guess is that it's a bug in Windows OS?

Comment: @user1146332 the OP specified that he uses macOS, so Windows bugs will not have much influence I think :)

Comment: However, the question is not really clear. Does the text show left to right in your source code in Texpad, or in the pdf preview? For the other two questions: you can set the font using the `fontspec` package, see [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf). For checking which fonts are available you can use the font tools of the OS, for example Font Book for Mac.

Comment: @Marijn It was just a metaphor referring to a username. Just making fun

Comment: @Marijn Very good, font is installed and working! text is LTR both in source code and in pdf

Comment: @Windows could you add a small example document to your question that shows your current setup? Make sure it is a complete document, i.e., it starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and it can be compiled without errors. This will make it much easier to identify what needs to be added to make the text RTL.

Comment: @Marijn https://ibb.co/3Y09gTY

Comment: @Windows it's better to add the code into the question (as text, not as image), because it does not risk that the link stops working and also it is easier to get an overview of the question if everything is put together. You can use the small `edit` link below the question text to add things to the question.

Comment: @Marijn done......